# gitlab create new user via api yields 404

Tags: ruby, http, gitlab

I'm able to do get requests to the gitlab api but I now want to programmatically create my first user. But every time I do a post request in Ruby:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://ip-address/api/v3/users")
http = Net::HTTP::new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.set_form_data({"username" => "username", "email" => "email@gmail.com", "password" => "password", "name" => "name"})
request["PRIVATE-TOKEN"] = "private-token"
response = http.request(request)
```

It shouldn't make a difference but i've tried this with a standard curl request, and with the gitlab ruby wrapper. For all of them my get requests work, but I get a 404 when trying to create a new user. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks a bit similar to https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6878#issuecomment-41779258

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented in [issue 6878](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6878#issuecomment-41468046):

> 404 is the default result so far for
>
> - password isn't acceptable
> - email isn't unique
> - username isn't unique

So make sure your `POST` isn't for a user with a password or email or name problem (like one mentioned in [issue 4209](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4209#issuecomment-26066544)).